# How to test Text Field Validate a comma exists in a field

Tags: javascript

How to test input Field  Validate a comma  exists in a input field ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var value = document.getElementById('id-of-the-form-field').value 
// or: var value = document.getElementsByName('name-of-the-form-field')[0].value

if(value.indexOf(',') > -1) {
    // value contains a comma
}
```

If this is not what you want, you have to give more details.

Reference: [`.indexOf()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_IndexOf.asp)

Answer (score -1):

```
str = document.getElementById(text_feild_id).value
arr = str.split(",")
if (arr.length>1){
  alert("comma exist");
}
```

or

```
   if (str.replace(/[^,]/g, "").length>=1){
      alert("comma exist");
    }
```

Comment: Your str.replace suggestion can fail if the str is null. The way you separated it, someone could get confused and put that in a place that leads to them getting a cannot call method of replace on undefined error.